# Assessing Sound Card Loads

Tags: audio, sound-card, mixer

Can someone with audio experience advise on how adding audio inputs (for multi-track recording, or other) breaks down? My computer comes with a stereo input, so I'm assuming it handles at least 1 stereo or 2 mono channels. But does that mean that's ALL it can handle? Let me pose 2 interrelated questions:

1. If I add 6 inputs through splitters / adapters but no external sound cards -- obviously that would be crude and clutter prone, but would it work?
   Assuming I were to use external sound cards, but use them as an array of really cheap (presumably low quality) $3 external usb sound cards in a hub, could I still hope to achieve decent multi track recording?
2. Suppose I have 1 microphone channel per sound card, and maybe 6 sound cards/mics altogether. Would there be a noticeable performance trade-off when compared to just using 1 higher-end sound card that has 6 built-in mic jacks? What is the metric for sound card loads (like what Ghz is to a CPU)?

I think that sums up my question pretty well, if specifics are needed about what kind of audio input sources I'm working with, I can provide them. For now, suffice as to say, it's nothing too intensive, just 6 mono-channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of recording separate mics on separate channels is that you can mix them later properly (adjust volume individually, adjust stereo effects individually). If you dont need that, or if you do the mix with analog hardware, or "splitters/adapters", then you could record 6 mics on one channel. (Or you could do a room recording in the first place). But if you want to mix afterwards, you need several channels.

USB bandwidth is limited, so don't expect to be able to use as many cheap soundcards as you like on a single USB port. 6 may already be the limit, maybe even less, because you usually can only get hubs with 4 ports, and two hubs might already be too much. In doubt, you'll have to experiment.

There's not much difference with respect to USB bandwidth needed between one higher-end sound"card" with many channels, and many cheap sound"cards" with one channel, except the overhead introduced by USB hubs.

But I'd assume you can get a reasonable higher end one for the price of several low end ones, and the quality of your recording will be much better.

In your place I'd buy one higher end USB sound"card" with enough channels. That will give you better recording quality, is guaranteed to work with the USB bandwidth available, and will be generally less hassle.

Comment: +1 on avoiding multiple cheap USB sound cards; sounds like potential for some hideous sync issues too... & could you even persuade ASIO etc to even talk to 6 at once?? For a decent multi i/o device, you couldn't go far wrong with any from this list - https://www.gearslutz.com/board/best-studio-gear/1107810-top-five-audio-interfaces-under-300-a.html?

Comment: Ok thanks guys, your points are well taken. I do plan to mix afterwards. I need each source to go to a separate file. Anyway let me recap, in terms of performance, I'm losing recording quality, and facing potential sync issues? what do you mean ASIO talking to 6 sound cards?

Comment: ASIO is a proprietary audio routing driver from Steinberg, much lower latency than is built-into the OS. There is a 'free' version called ASIO4ALL that can be persuaded to connect to more software [it's Windows & I'm on Mac so I've never used it. I also have the fully-licenced 'real' version]. Whether either version could simultaneously command 6 interfaces is doubtful. See the following links [too long for one comment]  for more info than I could possibly précis...

Comment: http://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/using-multiple-audio-interfaces-together https://www.steinberg.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20010 & http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20484/how-to-make-asio-work-with-multiple-programs-simultaneously-how-can-i-listen-t btw, some of those interfaces I linked to earlier will come with freebie cut-down versions of good DAW software, more than sufficient for a beginner/semi-pro.

Comment: ok those links had really good info too. I think I almost have all the info I need for my sound card purchase. Two follow up questions: Is there any limitations of using the OS's usbaudio.sys file with multi-track recording, in other words, as we add recording inputs, is there a greater propensity for latency issues? Secondly, If I have a decent external sound card with 6-8 mic jacks, will I still have the bandwidth restriction of using USB audio? Once I am over 6 or so, should I use fire wire to connect? Or are there other rules of thumb relevant here?

Comment: It's been a while since I needed a lot of inputs, but I used to run 24 i/o on a Pentium 4 with WinXP, so it's probably not much of a strain in itself. https://www.thomann.de/gb/usb_audio_interfaces.html?filter=true&feature-14239-first=16&feature-14239-last=32 has 16-32 channel devices, most USB capable, as well as some firewire. Not cheap though when you get into the 'real gear', but it going to be better to have more channels than you think you need rather than suddenly find you want another two :/

Comment: If you have a multichannel USB sound card that's rated for, say, USB 2.0, then it will reliably deliver all channels at the given sample rate on USB 2.0, assuming nothing else is using the same USB bus. So you just don't have to worry about bandwidth. I'd recommend recording all channels as different channels into the same file, makes keeping everything in sync a lot easier. I can't answer the OS specific questions (ask a new question, and add your OS as tag).